# Is it possible to connect to Google Coral Accelerator using mdt from host machine

Tags: google-coral

I have a google coral USB accelerator with Ubuntu 18.04 host. Able to run the predefined models with the same.

Can I connect to the device using Mendel Development Tool (mdt)? Is there any OS running in the accelerator?

Answer (score 2):

There is no OS running on the Coral USB Accelerator.

If you see the installation instruction `sudo apt-get install libedgetpu1-std` at https://coral.ai/docs/accelerator/get-started/#on-linux, it installs the edgetpu library package on your machine and enables communication between edgetpu and your machine. 
So, Coral USB Accelerator is used to enhance the capability of your machine itself to run Machine Learning programs more faster.

Mendel Development Tool (mdt) is a wrapper over SSH which needs to be installed on your host machine and not on the Coral Dev Board. Mendel OS by default comes with MDT client packages installed with it.

Comment: Thank you Manoj, so this means we cannot connect to coral accelerator from host PC using mdt. ?

Comment: No, the accelerator doesn't have an OS. You run everything on your host machine and interact with the Accelerator via libedgetpu